# Savings CloudKit RecordID to CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have a array of CloudKit records and want to store the record ID in to core data so when i query the cloud again i do not pull down the same records.  I just do a NSpRedicate not contain the records from core data.

However, getting an error, how do I save a record ID to core data.. Think it is a Type issue.

Current Code:

```
 coreData.recordRecordID = self.cloudKitRecords[0].recordID as? String
```

Current getting the error that CKRecord as String always fails, which I am not surprised.  Need to be able to save the recordID then get the recordID from core data.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the id like this:

```
coreData.recordRecordID = self.cloudKitRecords[0].recordID.recordName
```

It will then be a string.
If you want to make a CKRecordID from that, then you can create one using

```
var myID = = CKRecordID(recordName: yourStringID)
```

Comment: Note that the same record ID can exist in different zones so if you use multiple zones you'll want to include the zone ID if you need this identifier to be truly unique.

Answer (score 8):

```
import Foundation

import CoreData

import CloudKit

class Entity: NSManagedObject {

// MARK: - Properties

@NSManaged var recordID: CKRecordID?

// Additional properties here

}
```

Then change the Core Data attribute type to `Transformable` instead of `String`.

Comment: What is the cons/pros to use this approach instead of Edwin suggestion?

Comment: @flinth Con: None foreseen Pro: A 'CKRecordID' consists of a recordName ('String') and 'CKRecordZone'. It is important to save the 'CKRecordZone' along with the recordName when using zones other than just the default zone. Even if you are not using other zones now, this will safeguard you for the future. Note: You can save just the metadata of a record using the 'encodeSystemFieldsWithCoder' (see docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014044-CH1-SW30)). I can post code on for using the encoder if you need it.